# How to manipulate by relative output path of Vinyl file inside gulp pipeline?

Tags: node.js, gulp, node.js-stream

In the below gulp task, `targetFile.relative` (property of [Vinyl](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) instance)
will bee concatenated to `dest` path. For example if `targetFile.relative` is `images/icons/HamburgerMenu__Icon.svg`, output path will be `<Project absolute path>/dest/images/icons/HamburgerMenu__Icon.svg`

```
gulp.src('source/singletonComponents/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(gulp.dest( targetVinylFile => {          
      return 'dest'
    }));
```

What if we want to change `targetFile.relative`? For example, we want to output to `dest/pictures/icons/HamburgerMenu__Icon.svg`, but we don't want to rename source forlder `images` to `pictures`.

Because in this question we are considering the output path manipulation, please, not not touch source files/directories, and also `'source/singletonComponents/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)'` in solutions.

And also: it you think that it's not possible, please answer such as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the specific example you gave, you can trivially get the effect you wan with:

```
gulp.src('source/singletonComponents/images/icons/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/pictures/icons'));
```

The pattern above changes what is stored in the `relative` field of the files. They are now all relative to `source/singletonComponents/images/icons/`, which allows you in `gulp.dest` to alter the path to get the result you want.

If your real situation is more complicated you can manipulate the paths yourself through `pipe`:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const map = require("map-stream");
const path = require("path");

gulp.task("default", () =>
          gulp.src('source/singletonComponents/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
          .pipe(map((file, cb) => {
            file.path = path.join(file.base, file.relative.replace(/images/, "pictures"));
            cb(null, file);
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dest')));
```

Note that Gulp 4 does not allow modifying `file.relative` directly. You get an error if you try to do it. That's because it is derived from `file.base` and `file.path`. So you have to modify one of these or both if you want to change `file.relative`. Remember that `file.path` is the absolute path of the file. That's why we joint `file.base` to the modified value of `file.relative`.